# Poll user location every day between specific hours using AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am using `AlarmManager` to poll user location periodically which is working fine- Now I would like to give my app users an option so they can restrict the location polling by specifying hours say 'Between 8PM to 10PM'.

Right now I am using `AlarmManager.setRepeating` method for scheduling but I am unable to configure my alarm service so that it runs every day but within certain hours.
I already know how to schedule a recurring task using `AlarmManager` at particular time of day but how to set the end time is what I am looking for.

Comment: i feel operations like this should be in service... since you are not assured when BroadCaste Receivers would end..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't tell `AlarmManager` to do exactly that, but you could check whenever your service gets called to see if it's within the specified hours. If it is, then you proceed as normal, if not then you reschedule the alarm to start at the beginning of the next polling period.

Comment: yes this is what I am thinking to do, but I am concerned about the battery, that if somehow it is possible to specify start/end time my background service don't have to consume the battery when the current time is not within set limits

Comment: It should be fine as long as you reschedule (and not just ignore). That way you only get one extra call every day.